# Recursively compare two directories with diff -r without output on broken links

Tags: diff

I am using `diff -r a b` to recursively compare directories **a** and **b**. It often happens though that there are some broken links (the same broken links in both **a** and **b** directories and pointing to the same, non-existing targets).

**diff** then outputs error messages for those cases and exits with a non-zero exit code, however I would like it to stay silent, and exit with 0 as the directories are the same in my book.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you still want the symlinks compared (and identified as equivalent but broken), or is it acceptable to ignore all symlinks when doing this diff?

Comment: compared and identified as equivalent, I don't care if they are broken. I am just trying to verify that my rsync worked.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For version 3.3 or later of `diff`, you should use the `--no-dereference` option, as described in [Pete Harlan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119406/22651).

Unfortunately, older versions of `diff` [don't support ignoring symlinks](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?%28diff.info%29Special%20Files):

> Some files are neither directories nor regular files: they are unusual
>   files like symbolic links, device special files, named pipes, and
>   sockets.  Currently, `diff` treats symbolic links like regular files;
>   it treats other special files like regular files if they are specified
>   at the top level, but simply reports their presence when comparing
>   directories.  This means that `patch` cannot represent changes to such
>   files.  For example, if you change which file a symbolic link points
>   to, `diff` outputs the difference between the two files, instead of
>   the change to the symbolic link.
>
> `diff` should optionally report changes to special files specially,
>   and `patch` should be extended to understand these extensions.

If all you want is to verify an rsync (and presumably fix what's missing), then you could just run the rsync command a second time. If you don't want to do that, then [check-summing the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657232/143804) may be sufficient.

If you really want to do this with `diff`, then you can use `find` to skip the symlinks, and run diff on each file individually. Pass your directories **a** and **b** in as arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Skip files in $1 which are symlinks
for f in `find $1/* ! -type l`
do
    # Suppress details of differences
    diff -rq $f $2/${f##*/}
done
```

or as a one-liner:

```
for f in `find a/* ! -type l`;do diff -rq $f b/${f##*/};done
```

This will identify files that differ in content, or files which are in **a** but not in **b**.

Note that:

- since we are skipping symlinks entirely, this won't notice if symlink names are not present in **b**. If you required that, you would need a second find pass to identify all the symlinks and then explicitly check for their existence in **b**.
- Extra files in **b** will not be identified, since the list is constructed from the contents of **a**. This probably isn't a problem for your `rsync` scenario.

Comment: The proposed script does not work recursively for any directories present in directory 'a' (the paths created for 'b' using b/${f##*} are not correct).

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - Yes, you're right. I think the solution is to remove a #, e.g. `for f in `find a/* ! -type l`;do echo $f b/${f#*/};done`. I don't have time to test this right now though. Let me know if that works.

Comment: It *is* better however it still messes up the filepaths in many cases. The script (with a # removed) appears to need to be invoked from a directory directly over 'a' to work.

Comment: This answer becomes obsolete when using GNU diff 3.3 (see postings below)

Comment: The script above has several problems, due to first finding all file names and feeding them to an expanded command line. (1) It will only work with small collections of files since it. (2) Any file name with special character (even a space) won't be processed. (3) Always use `$(xxx)` instead of backticks. Backticks symmetry makes them less readable and prevents nesting. Regarding 1 and 2 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366184/find-while-loop-with-files-containing-spaces-in-bash

Answer (score 24):

Since version 3.3 GNU `diff` supports not dereferencing symlinks, but then compares the paths they point to.

Install GNU `diffutils` >= 3.3 and use the `--no-dereference` option; there is no short option for that.

Diagnostic will be silent if equal or:

Symbolic links `/tmp/noderef/a/symlink` and `/tmp/noderef/b/symlink` differ

Comment: Now if only it would show the content changes, as though the symlink were a regular file... :-/

Answer (score 10):

You can use a newer version of `diff`

The `diff` in GNU `diffutils` 3.3 includes a `--no-dereference` option that allows you to compare the symlinks themselves rather than their targets.  It reports if they differ, is quiet if they agree and doesn't care whether they're broken.

I don't know when the option was added; it isn't present in 2.8.1.

Comment: I can confirm is doesn't exist in diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2 either